# Given a rectangle, construct a square with equal area

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

Given a rectangle, construct a square with equal area.  *Note: Euclid provides this construction in II.14.  I wrote the construction below without looking at Euclid's solution, and request verification, critique, and improvement.*

**Solution:**

If $▭ABCD$ is a square, we are done.  Else, assume WLOG $AB < AD$.

Extend $AB$ through $B$ to point $Q$ such that $AQ \cong AD$, and find point $P$ on $AQ$ such that $AP \cong PQ$.  Draw circle $\bigcirc P$ with center $P$ and radius $AP$.  Extend $BC$ through $B$ until it intersects $\bigcirc P$ at point $X$.

Observe that $\angle AXQ$ is a right angle by Thales Theorem.

Construct a square with side $AX$ by extending $QX$ through $X$ to point $R$ such that $RX \cong AX$ and $RX \perp AX$.  By an argument similar to Euclid's proof of the Pythagorean Theorem (I.47), square $\square AXR$ has area equal to rectangle $▭ABCD$.

**Questions:** Is this construction correct? Please critique, improve, or comment on the approach, exposition, or anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assertion that a square with side $AX$ has the same area as the rectangle $ABCD$ is equivalent to the assertion that $AB:AX=AX:AD$. But $AD\cong AQ$ and you can use similar triangles to prove that $AB:AX=AX:AQ$, so the construction is correct.

The reasoning I gave above is rather premature for something in Euclid's Book II, so if you want to do the proofs in the same order then you are better off with the reasoning you gave.

Answer (score 1):

Your method is found to be having a square with the same area as that of the given rectangle. Here is a more systematic approach for your consideration.

1. Extend AD to X such that DX = DC.
   [image]
2. Find M such that AM = MX.
3. Let the circle (centered at M with radius = AM) cut DC extended at Y.
4. Construct the required square using DY as its side.

This is because, by power of a point, $AD.DX = DY^2$.
I have the original picture replaced by a new one which has two more lines (in red, dotted) added.